# Flutter column with elements aligning to different sides without stretching the width of the column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to have a column take the width of the content, and have some elements align to right and some to the left.

Is this possible?

If I use Align widget on the children the whole column stretches in width. Is there another way?

Thank you

Edit: Example

```
Center(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
          ),
          Text('Here goes some text with variable length'),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

I want the column above with the red square to the left and the blue to the right (and the column not stretching to the available width).

Comment: can you show us an image on what you want to achieve

Comment: @ArbiterChil I put a code example. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired layout where the yellow `Container` adapts its width based on the content (text) and the squares align to the left and right, you can wrap the `Column` widget inside an `IntrinsicWidth` widget.

The `IntrinsicWidth` widget sizes its child to the child's maximum intrinsic width, which in this case is determined by the text.

Here's the updated code:

```
Center(
  child: IntrinsicWidth( // Add this !
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
          Text('Here goes some text'),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**EDIT:**
Other Option with `Stack`:

If interactivity is not required and the sizes of the widgets above and below are known, you can use this solution which is less resource intensive.
Otherwise the first solution with IntrisicWidth will have to be used.

```
Center(
  child: Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Text('Here goes some text'),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: -50,
        left: 0,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: -50,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: As stated before, this stretches the column to the full available width

Comment: I modified the code, try this

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have worked. I will award the bounty when possible (I have to wait 20 hours yet)

Comment: Is this best practice? This class is relatively expensive and should avoid using where possible https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html

Comment: It's possible to achieve this with a Stack if the sizes of the widgets above and below are known. 

However, they won't be interactive since they are positioned outside the bounds of the yellow container. The best approach depends on the specific use case. 

If interactivity is required, then using IntrinsicWidth might be a more suitable solution.

I also edited the code with the Stack example.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to put the contents of the column in a row, so you would have elements inside containers for their width and height as you like.
Column -> Row -> aligned containers.

Comment: Aligned container stretch the width of the column

Comment: If you put the column inside a container than you can edit this main container properties, also put the widgets inside the row in a container as well and adjust their properties.
ps: try to adjust the column properties such as mainAxis or crossAxis, they could be helpful or post more information with code/pic so we know what the problem is for sure.

Comment: No, I can't set a width to the Container because the width inside is variable. I put a sized box with a fixed width as an example, to show what I was trying to achieve. I'll edit the example from the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 100),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: it stretches the width of the column

Answer (score -1):

The `Container` has a null constraint so it will expand to the size of its children. My suggested solution is to add constraint to the `Container`.

Ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html

> Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be as small as possible. Containers with children size themselves to their children. The width, height, and constraints arguments to the constructor override this.

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, // Add constraints, in this example I am using the width of the screen
    ),
    color: Colors.yellow,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      Text('Here goes some text with variable length'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```